# Delete Cell without edit button in table view?

Tags: iphone

if i press the particular cell(edit button's action will be taken without pressing edit button) in table view. wiil you answer please?
th following code gives error...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSArray *deleteIndexPaths =[NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
    [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0],nil]; 
    UITableView *tv = (UITableView *)self.view;
    [tv beginUpdates];

   [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPathswithRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
   [tv endUpdates];

}
```

Comment: Can't really understand your question well. Use better punctuation and grammar. Have a look at http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7

Comment: What kind of error? Compile-time error because `tv` is not defined? Or some run-time error that you might be able to copy and paste into your question? Or just a visual glitch that you might describe?

Answer (score 1):

You need also to delete the source of that cell from the datasource as tableview will try to reload the data after the update. Basically you need to update the result of

```
    numberOfSectionsInTableView
```

and 
        numberOfRowsInSection

so that it is relevant after the update.